# Extracting Tag-Specific XML Data into an Array with DOMDocument and foreach

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach, domdocument

I am trying to extract data from a XML document and create an array with it. I am using `DOMdocument` and `foreach` loops to extract the data that I want. The data I am after is within the `<description>` tag; **however I only want `<description>` data that is preceded by `<header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>`.** Note other `<description>` data is preceded by the tags `<header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>` and `<header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>`, I don't want that data.

Here is a preview of the XML and how it is structured:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
  <VehicleDescription country="US" language="en" modelYear="2015" bestMakeName="Audi" bestModelName="A4" bestStyleName="4dr Sdn Auto quattro 2.0T Premium" bestTrimName="Premium" xmlns="urn:description7b.services.chrome.com">
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>Engine: 2.0L DOHC 4-Cylinder TFSI -inc: Audi valvelift system</description>
        <category id="1048"/>
        <category id="1054"/>
        <category id="1213"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>Transmission: 8-Speed Automatic w/Tiptronic -inc: sport program and manual shift mode</description>
        <category id="1130"/>
        <category id="1195"/>
        <category id="1220"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>Full-Time All-Wheel Drive</description>
        <category id="1041"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>Engine Oil Cooler</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>80-Amp/Hr Maintenance-Free Battery w/Run Down Protection</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>150 Amp Alternator</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>Gas-Pressurized Shock Absorbers</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>Front And Rear Anti-Roll Bars</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>Electric Power-Assist Speed-Sensing Steering</description>
        <category id="1084"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>16.1 Gal. Fuel Tank</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>Single Stainless Steel Exhaust</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>Multi-Link Front Suspension w/Coil Springs</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>Multi-Link Rear Suspension w/Coil Springs</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>
        <description>4-Wheel Disc Brakes w/4-Wheel ABS, Front Vented Discs, Brake Assist, Hill Hold Control and Electric Parking Brake</description>
        <category id="1018"/>
        <category id="1020"/>
        <category id="1228"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Wheels: 8.0J x 17" 10-Spoke-Star-Design</description>
        <category id="1123"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Tires: P245/45R17 AS</description>
        <category id="1092"/>
        <category id="1097"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Wheels w/Silver Accents</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Steel Spare Wheel</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Compact Spare Tire Mounted Inside Under Cargo</description>
        <category id="1098"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Clearcoat Paint</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Express Open/Close Sliding And Tilting Glass 1st Row Sunroof w/Sunshade</description>
        <category id="1069"/>
        <category id="1132"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Body-Colored Front Bumper</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Body-Colored Rear Bumper</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Rocker Panel Extensions</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Aluminum Side Windows Trim and Black Front Windshield Trim</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Body-Colored Door Handles</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Body-Colored Power Heated Side Mirrors w/Manual Folding and Turn Signal Indicator</description>
        <category id="1064"/>
        <category id="1065"/>
        <category id="1174"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Fixed Rear Window w/Defroster</description>
        <category id="1034"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Light Tinted Glass</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Speed Sensitive Rain Detecting Variable Intermittent Wipers w/Heated Jets</description>
        <category id="1127"/>
        <category id="1159"/>
        <category id="1160"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Galvanized Steel/Aluminum Panels</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Black Grille w/Chrome Surround</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Trunk Rear Cargo Access</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Programmable Projector Beam High Intensity Low/High Beam Daytime Running Auto-Leveling Headlamps w/Washer and Delay-Off</description>
        <category id="1061"/>
        <category id="1168"/>
        <category id="1169"/>
        <category id="1313"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Front And Rear Fog Lamps</description>
        <category id="1151"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Cornering Lights</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>Perimeter/Approach Lights</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1176">EXTERIOR</header>
        <description>LED Brakelights</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="10689">ENTERTAINMENT</header>
        <description>Radio: Audi Concert System w/1CD Player -inc: MP3 capable, AM/FM radio, auxiliary input jack, SD card slots w/32GB capacity for MP3 files, speed-dependent volume control, Audi MMI radio plus system for controlling infotainment/climate/car setup w/6.5" color screen, Audi music interface w/iPod integration w/1 cable for iPod connection, Audi 6-channel DSP extended 180 watt sound system w/10 speakers including subwoofer and SiriusXM satellite radio w/90-day trial subscription</description>
        <category id="1014"/>
        <category id="1017"/>
        <category id="1149"/>
        <category id="1150"/>
        <category id="1230"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="10689">ENTERTAINMENT</header>
        <description>Radio w/Clock and Steering Wheel Controls</description>
        <category id="1161"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="10689">ENTERTAINMENT</header>
        <description>Audio Theft Deterrent</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="10689">ENTERTAINMENT</header>
        <description>Window Grid Diversity Antenna</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="10689">ENTERTAINMENT</header>
        <description>Bluetooth Wireless Phone Connectivity</description>
        <category id="1211"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Power Front Seats -inc: 8-way power front seats and 4-way power lumbar adjustment for driver</description>
        <category id="1074"/>
        <category id="1075"/>
        <category id="1082"/>
        <category id="1189"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Driver Seat</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Passenger Seat</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>60-40 Folding Bench Front Facing Fold Forward Seatback Rear Seat</description>
        <category id="1076"/>
        <category id="1304"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Manual Tilt/Telescoping Steering Column</description>
        <category id="1087"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Gauges -inc: Speedometer, Odometer, Engine Coolant Temp, Tachometer, Oil Level, Trip Odometer and Trip Computer</description>
        <category id="1203"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Power Rear Windows</description>
        <category id="1126"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Leather Steering Wheel</description>
        <category id="1192"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Front Cupholder</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Rear Cupholder</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Front Cigar Lighter(s)</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Ashtray</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Valet Function</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Power Fuel Flap Locking Type</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Remote Keyless Entry w/Integrated Key Transmitter, 4 Door Curb/Courtesy, Illuminated Entry and Panic Button</description>
        <category id="1062"/>
        <category id="1063"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Remote Releases -Inc: Power Cargo Access</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>HomeLink Garage Door Transmitter</description>
        <category id="1204"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Cruise Control</description>
        <category id="1033"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Dual Zone Front Automatic Air Conditioning</description>
        <category id="1009"/>
        <category id="1010"/>
        <category id="1011"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Rear HVAC w/Separate Controls</description>
        <category id="1011"/>
        <category id="1012"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>HVAC -inc: Underseat Ducts and Console Ducts</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Illuminated Locking Glove Box</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Driver Foot Rest</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Interior Trim -inc: Aluminum Instrument Panel Insert, Aluminum Door Panel Insert, Aluminum Console Insert and Aluminum/Metal-Look Interior Accents</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Full Cloth Headliner</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Leatherette Door Trim Insert</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Leather Gear Shift Knob</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Leather Seating Surfaces</description>
        <category id="1078"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Day-Night Rearview Mirror</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Driver And Passenger Visor Vanity Mirrors w/Driver And Passenger Illumination</description>
        <category id="1175"/>
        <category id="1176"/>
        <category id="1177"/>
        <category id="1178"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Full Floor Console w/Storage, Mini Overhead Console w/Storage and 3 12V DC Power Outlets</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Front And Rear Map Lights</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Fade-To-Off Interior Lighting</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Full Carpet Floor Covering -inc: Carpet Front And Rear Floor Mats</description>
        <category id="1055"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Carpet Floor Trim and Carpet Trunk Lid/Rear Cargo Door Trim</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Cargo Space Lights</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>FOB Controls -inc: Trunk/Hatch/Tailgate, Windows and Sunroof/Convertible Roof</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Driver / Passenger And Rear Door Bins</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Power 1st Row Windows w/Front And Rear 1-Touch Up/Down</description>
        <category id="1126"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Delayed Accessory Power</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Power Door Locks w/Autolock Feature</description>
        <category id="1063"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Systems Monitor</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Redundant Digital Speedometer</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Trip Computer</description>
        <category id="1203"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Outside Temp Gauge</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Analog Display</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Manual Anti-Whiplash Adjustable Front Head Restraints and Manual Adjustable Rear Head Restraints</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Front Center Armrest and Rear Center Armrest w/Storage</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>2 Seatback Storage Pockets</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Perimeter Alarm</description>
        <category id="1013"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Immobilizer III Engine Immobilizer</description>
        <category id="1166"/>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>3 12V DC Power Outlets</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
     <standard>
        <header id="1220">INTERIOR</header>
        <description>Air Filtration</description>
        <styleId>369101</styleId>
        <installed cause="BaseEquipment"/>
     </standard>
  </VehicleDescription>
```

Using the following PHP I was able to extract ALL `description` data from the XML document. However, I have been unable to determine how to pull only `description` data that is tied to the `<header id="1236">MECHANICAL</header>`. How can I edit the following code to achieve this?

```
<?php

  $xml = file_get_contents('note.xml');
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadXML($xml);

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('standard') as $standard){

    $mechdescription = $standard->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $mecharray[] = $mechdescription;

   }
    foreach ($mecharray as $displaymech){

     echo $displaymech."<br>";

   }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an if condition to filter out unwanted results

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('standard') as $standard){
  if ($standard->getElementsByTagName('header')->item(0)->getAttribute('id') == '1236'){
    $mechdescription = $standard->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $mecharray[] = $mechdescription;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Not working for me. See link: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8108077b5b15e971e3003dc699d7faf8b025d9f6

Comment: @mugelloblue there was a typo, try now

Comment: ahh yes, `getAttribute` was misspelled. I should have caught that. Thanks again, @Musa !